# How to invalidate all users from all browsers and machines in tornado

Tags: python-2.7, cookies, tornado

After successful authentication the user I am setting following -

```
self.set_secure_cookie('user', str(user.id), 1)
self.set_secure_cookie('expires_days', 1)
self.set_secure_cookie('max_age_days', 1)
```

Now the requirement is to logout all users on a specific action. For this I am trying -

```
self.clear_all_cookies()
```

but this is only logging out the current user. Not other users logged-in from other machines or browsers.

I am using tornado 4.3 and Python 2.7

Any way I this can be acheived?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the cookies of all "connected" users with in one go as each request is handled separately, but you can try invalidating them so they can be deleted on their next request.

A simple solution would be to store a `cookies_valid_from` timestamp in your `Application` and on user login set a `created_on` timestamp cookie for the user. Your `get_current_user()` function could look like this:

```
def get_current_user(self):
    if self.get_secure_cookie("created_on") < self.application.cookies_valid_from:
        self.clear_all_cookies()
        return None

    return self.get_secure_cookie("user")
```

The specific "log out all users" action you mention can simply update the `cookies_valid_from` timestamp to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

To invalidate absolutely *everything*, you can simply change your cookie secret. All existing cookies will be ignored and you can begin issuing new ones. But if you need something more nuanced than that, you'll have to design it in to your authentication protocol. For example, don't just store the user ID in the cookie, store a session ID and keep track of the currently-valid session IDs in a database or cache. Then you can invalidate user sessions by deleting their IDs from the database.